# Is it possible to print line-by-line on a network usb printer using Qt on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, printing

The title says pretty much everything, I have to convert old com/serial-printer-port code to 'new flashy Qt code' that should work with a network usb printer.

I have searched quite a lot and I can't find anything about how to print line-by-line (ie. when I send just one text line to the printer, it shouldn't print a whole page).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

ps. It doesn't have to be Qt (as long as I can wrap it / use it from Qt) but it must be C++ and function on a WinXP.

Comment: Would it be okay if you cached the lines until you have one complete page and print it then?

Comment: Well no, that's the big problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page documents the Windows APIs that can be used to send raw data to a printer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162959(v=vs.85).aspx

This might be OK if you only want to print simple text.

I don't know of a way to use the drawing capabilities of Windows to print less than a page.

Comment: I've sifted through endless pages of code and it was you who got it, Thanks it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the printer you have. Forget laser printers and better Ink Jet printers. Best is probably a dot matrix printer, a GDI printer should work as well.

Microsoft has a page on doing exactly what you want to do, using the Win32API: [How To Print Line-by-Line to a Printer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175083) There is an example at that page.